# Which format of "May 28, 2013 6:04:38 PM"?

Tags: java

I trying parse the String  "May 28, 2013 6:04:38 PM" to Date with SimpleDateFormat, but I couldn't do it. Below is what I did:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    try {
        System.out.println(sdf.parse("May 28, 2013 6:04:38 PM"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "May 28, 2013 6:04:38 PM"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:377)
at com.test(DateUtil.java:71)
```

Comment: and what is the error

Comment: ready, I edited a question

Comment: `May` != `Maio` - try `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.US);` (mais indicado user `LocalDateTime` e outras classes do package [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html))

Comment: By the way, I suggest educating the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for exchanging date-time values as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, y h:mm:ss a");
        String datestr = "May 28, 2013 1:04:38 PM";
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(datestr, dtf);
        System.out.println(dateTime.format(dtf));
```